# Typeorm "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'entity.entityId' in 'where clause'"

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to do a search by filtering the results based on the categories, on the following entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Anime {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;


  @ManyToMany(type => Category)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];
}

@Entity()
export class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: 'Descrição não fornecida' })
  description: string;
}
```

for this I am using this function that uses the find options of the typeorm as prescribed in the documentation:

```
    constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Anime) private readonly db: Repository<Anime>,
  ) {}

    async findAll(
    limit: number,
    page: number,
    whereOptions: WhereExpression,
    orderOptions: OrderByCondition,
  ): Promise<Anime[]> {
    try {
      const animes = await this.db.find({
        take: limit,
        skip: page,
        where: {
          categories: { id: '6a999dc1-20a7-43c7-b6e2-b6eb0c883875' },
        },
        order: orderOptions,
        join: {
          alias: 'a',
          leftJoinAndSelect: {
            categories: 'a.categories',
          },
        },
        relations: ['categories'],
      });
      return animes;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new SqlException(e);
    }
  }
```

The error is as follows:

> "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'a.animeId' in 'where clause'"

I know that this column does not really exist in the anime entity, but shouldn't it be doing this filtering in the join column? can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or how to fix this bug?

Comment: Same error here with `@ManyToMany`, did you find any solution?